# how to put some variables into List

Tags: flutter, dart

i have 3 variable for `dropdownValue` to put in a List, how to do it is it possible ?
because i want to make 3 dropdown by looping the list and give every dropdown the value from the list

```
  String dropdownValue1;
  String dropdownValue2;
  String dropdownValue3;

  List dropdownValue = []
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this way:

```
List<String> dropdownValues = ["dropdownValue1","dropdownValue2","dropdownValue3"];
```

### And to use the values:

`dropdownValues[index]` //replace the index with the value you want to pick

Comment: i think asker wants to add variables in the array...not direct strings

Answer (score 1):

Values that we put in the array are should not be null. In your code `dropdownValue1`, `dropdownValue2`, `dropdownValue3` values are null that's when you add them to the array you get an error.

try adding values to variables and them in the array.

Example code:

```
String dropdownValue1 = "dropdownValue1";
String dropdownValue2 = "dropdownValue2";
String dropdownValue3 = "dropdownValue3";

List<String> dropdownValue = [
  dropdownValue1,
  dropdownValue2,
  dropdownValue3
];
```

Comment: it says the value1, 2, 3 cannot bi initializer

Comment: what ?? can you please tell me your issue specifically?

Comment: when i put the dropdownValue1 in List, the dropdownValue1 got red underline and it says it cannot be initializer

Comment: can you please post the updated code??